# try_mutate compared to getting & setting

Tags: storage

As I understand [transactional storage](https://docs.substrate.io/build/runtime-storage/#transactional-storage), an error result from an extrinsic reverts any state changes by default (assuming no `without_transactional` macros or suchlike).

Some feel that because of this, use of `Storage*` functions like `try_mutate` for storage operations is no longer needed.  They prefer an easier to read style of fetching a record into a mut variable from storage, perform checks & updates, and then call `set` (with `Some(foo)` or `None`) when done.

When I look at the code (e.g. in [frame/support/src/storage/generator/map](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/820179348c1c56bbe00236be6115a7bab451d1fd/substrate/frame/support/src/storage/generator/map.rs#L286)) I'm not seeing an obvious reason to prefer functions like `try_mutate` and friends (assuming of course all proper error conditions are still checked). Is there a technical reason to stick with these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question feels like:

- `3 * 3` vs `3^2`
- `use sp_std::vec::Vec` vs `use alloc::vec::Vec`

There's no particular reason.

I prefer using `try_mutate` when I'm trying to enhance an existing `mutate` code. That makes code more concise.

`get`, `set` and `if-else` can also handle this.

Both ways are fine; it simply depends on people's habits.

Comment: Well substrate code is quite a bit more complicated than 3*3 vs 3^2.   All I needed to know is whether there was a technical reason (that I might have missed) vs. a stylistic one.  So thank at least for answering that part.